# Simple way to create this 3-D pixel effect in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, logo

[image]

It's the sad, pixelated little icon that appears when Google Chrome doesn't shut down correctly.

Given a, say, off white on dark gray pixel image to use in a design, how would I get the edges of the pixels to have a shadow as in the frowny face above, in GIMP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you put your faux pixels into a separate layer that has a transparent background, you can use the **Drop Shadow** filter as described in the [GIMP Documentation](http://docs.gimp.org/en/script-fu-drop-shadow.html), and it looks like the settings might be these:

- Offset X: 0
- Offset Y: 2
- Blur Radius: 1
- Color: black
- Opacity: 60%

There is also a 1px light yellow line on the tops of the pixels, which you can see if you zoom in far enough. You could probably achieve this with filters, but i'd just add it manually using the Pencil tool at 1px size, because it's so simple.